# Does grep process line by line or entire file?

Tags: unix, grep

As I'm learning more about UNIX commands I started working with sed at work.  Sed's design reads a file in line by line, and executes commands on each line individually.

How does grep process files?  I've tried various ways of googling "does grep process line by line" and nothing really concrete shows up.

Comment: grep doesn't process anything by itself. grep used to filter by pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Why GNU grep is fast](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) :

> Moreover, GNU grep AVOIDS BREAKING THE INPUT INTO LINES.  Looking for newlines would slow grep down by a factor of several times, because to find the newlines it would have to look at every byte!

and then

> - Don't look for newlines in the input until after you've found a match.

Comment: +1.  In order to process the input line-by-line, use the option `--line-buffered`.  However, the manual says: `Use line buffering on output. This can cause a performance penalty.`

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
I will correct myself. It is neither line by line nor full file, its in terms of chunks of data which are placed into the buffer.

More details are here http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you pass to grep doesn't have any way of specifying newlines (although you can specify matches against the start or end of a line).

So it appears to work line by line, even though actually it may not treat line ends differently to other characters.